# I am getting type String is not a subtype of type int in my flutter project

Tags: flutter

I downloaded a flutter project and tried to run it, but I get this error

```
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'
```

And the error is pointing me the this code

```
int? identified = _allBackEnds.getUser(IDENTIFIED);
```

IDENTIFIED is defined in a file called `strings.dart` like this

const IDENTIFIED = "identified";

as well as other strings such as

```
const FIRST_NAME = "firstName";
const LAST_NAME = "lastName";
```

I notice the problem causing the error is because IDENTIFIED is a string.

What I don't understand is, in the same file where there is an error there are other variables like this

```
   String fName = _allBackEnds.getUser(FIRST_NAME);
   String lName = _allBackEnds.getUser(LAST_NAME);
```

And they all return data in a text widget

```
  Text(
    fName.capitalize()! + " " + lName.capitalize()!,
  ),
```

So I don't understand how the string is been used to return data and why I am getting an error

PS - This might sound confusing, and I hope you understand the question

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the signature of the `_allBackEnds.getUser()` method?
I think that you need to change int? to String? in the first line of your question.

```
String? identified = _allBackEnds.getUser(IDENTIFIED);
```